# Does std::list's erase member function call the destructor for all stored elements?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, std, destructor

I am debugging one memory issue it has some relation with the `std::list::erase` method.

While reading the documentation for `std::list::erase`, I saw [this statement](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/):

> "This effectively reduces the container size by the number of elements removed, which are destroyed."

I am having difficulty in understanding this statement. As an example, consider this setup:

```
class demo {

};
std::list<demo *> mylist;
```

Now, suppose I call `mylist.erase(iterator of list)`. I thought that this would call the destructor for class `demo`, but it doesn't seem to, which seems to contradict the statement "which are destroyed."

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: The pointer is destroyed (which is a no-op). The pointee isn't. (And this is a good example of why you shouldn't use owning raw pointers - especially containers of them.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the `clear()` method of the list, it will destroy all of the objects stored inside of the list. In your case, you have a list of `demo*`s This means that each of the *pointers* will be destroyed, since the *pointers* are stored inside the list, but the *pointees* won't be destroyed because the *pointees* aren't stored inside the list. In other words, destroying the pointers isn't the same as calling `delete` on each of those pointers. As a result, it's usually not recommended to store raw pointers in container types if those pointers own the objects they point at, since, as you've just seen, the destructors aren't called automatically.

Now, on the other hand, suppose you have a `list<unique_ptr<demo>>`. In that case, calling `clear()` will destroy all the `unique_ptr<demo>`s in the list. This in turn will deallocate the objects that the `unique_ptr`s point at, since destroying a `unique_ptr` also destroys the object it points at. This works because `unique_ptr` has an idea of ownership and realizes that it needs to destroy the object it points at when it is itself destroyed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

And just to clarify, erase() also destroys the element in the same way that clear() does.

```
// Removes the element from the list and destroys it:
mylist.erase(iterator);
```